# Using ng-repeat just to parse but not print that many amount of html element

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` in a div to parse through array and print some data. 
Inside that `ng-repeat` I use another `ng-repeat` in a div to parse through some other array and show that data. But when I parse through the second `ng-repeat`, it again prints 2 divs because the array has 2 objects inside it. But I dont what that the second `ng-repeat` print 2 divs. I just want it to parse through array and print what I need.

this is the code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="a in property">
    <p>{{a.name}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="b in proprent">
        <p ng-if="b.propid == a.id">{{ b.rent }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

these are the arrays : 
property = 
[{"id" : 1, "name" : "A"},{"id" : 2,"name" : "B"}]
and 
proprent = 
[{"propid"= 1, "rent" = 6000},{"propid" = 2, "rent" = 7000,}]

What my code does is it prints 2 divs again when parsing through proprent, but I just what it to compare the ID from property and print the rent. How do I do that?

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: I am using angularjs 1.2

Comment: it seems to work fine with version 1.2.1

Comment: I dont know how is it not working for me :/

Comment: I would approach this in a different way, creating a new array of objects or adding the rent property to each object of the `property array` and use just one `ng-repeat` printing `a.name` and `a.rent`.

Comment: I agree with @Fotis it would be much better

Comment: Oh yeah! That could be done too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the logic in your controller

```
$scope.property = $scope.property.map((prop) => {
  prop.proprent = $scope.proprent.filter((propr) => {
    return propr.propid === prop.id
  })

  return prop;
})
```

and then in your templates

```html
<div ng-repeat="a in property">
    <p>{{a.name}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="b in a.proprent">
        <p>{{ b.rent }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```